# cakephp - has many through not saving

Tags: cakephp

I have the following has many through relationship

```
Alert            AlertsElement       Search 
 id               id                  id 
 name             alert_id            link 
                  search_id
                  ordering
```

Here are my models

```
class Alert extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Alert';
var $hasMany = array('AlertsElement');  

class AlertsElement extends AppModel {
var $name = 'AlertsElement';
var $belongsTo = array('Alert','Search');

class Search extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Search';
var $hasMany = array('AlertsElement');
```

Here is my test code I am using to do a save -

```
$d = array();
$d['Alert']['id'] = 1976;
$d['Search']['id'] = 107;
$d['AlertsElement']['ordering'] = 2;
$this->Alert->create();
$this->Alert->saveAll($d);
```

I get this error -

```
Cannot use a scalar value as an array [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1696]
```

and a row entry in alertselement with the order but the foreign keys set to 0

Any ideas ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to save a `hasMany` relationship with `saveAll`, the `hasMany`-associated model data (in this case, `$d['AlertsElement']`) needs to be an indexed array of associative arrays, thus:

```
$d = array(
  'Alert' => array(
    'id' => 1976
  ),
  'AlertsElements' => array(
    0 => array(
      'ordering' => 2
    ) 
  )
);
$this->Alert->saveAll($d);
```

Note that the associative array, consisting of the `'ordering'` key and its value, has been shifted down into an indexed array. This is the required format for saving `hasMany`-associated data in a single `saveAll` operation, because this format expands gracefully  whether you want to save one or ten associated records.

Refer to the Cake manual on [saving related model data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for answering both my questions, where would the search id go ?

Comment: Unfortunately, since the `Search` model isn't directly associated with the `Alert` model, you can't save the `Search` model in the same call. This is just a limitation of Cake's ORM. You'll have to save the `Search` record in the post-save logic, or in an `afterSave` callback of the `AlertsElement` model.

Comment: Thanks for the help, wasted hell lot of time figuring out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got here looking for a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129942/cakephp-using-saveall-how-do-i-save-extra-data-with-the-habtm-link-record). Not to contradict Daniel, the book says that when you use a [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo#!/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model) relationship (which is what Alex is using), you *can* save all three records with a single `saveAll` call, but you do it from the joining table's model like this:

```
$data = array(
    [Student] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Joe
            [last_name] => Bloggs
        )

    [Course] => Array
        (
            [name] => Cake
        )

    [CourseMembership] => Array
        (
            [days_attended] => 5
            [grade] => A
        )

);
$this->CourseMembership->saveAll($data);
```

Unless I've misread the book, that example should create the Student, Course, and joining CourseMembership records. That said, I have yet to be able to get it to work as documented. I'm passing in an id for the Course as I'm using an existing Course, but it doesn't create the Student or the CourseMembership record.

Any more feedback appreciated.